# How to create this Popup form in ASP.Net using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working with a web site in `ASP.NET` for the practice and I want to make the popup form like [beemp3](http://beemp3.com/). When we click on `Playlist Login` or `Playlist SignUp` a popup form comes on with transparent background but we can't access the controls on the page given behind.
I'm not much familiar with the `JavaScript` or other scripting languages. My teacher told me that they are using `JQuery` to creating this popup menu but I know little bit `JavaScript` so I want to know that how can I accomplish this task using `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is a JavaScript library that can make doing things in java script simpler and easier.
There are many plugins for jquery that can help you doing what you need , Jquery Tools for example has overlay controls, take a look at:

[http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/trigger.htm](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/trigger.html)

Comment: broken link; couldn't quickly find a replacement.